Why core dump is pointing to Oracle library?
I'm facing an issue where core dump is happening randomly in a particular process in a production server running RHEL 8.8 - sometimes it takes place within a span of one week and sometimes takes many days to re-occur. Below are the stack traces: -
#0 0x00007fd45ff4cacf in raise () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6

#1 0x00007fd463162a8f in skgesigOSCrash () from /opt/oracle/client/product/19.12.0_64/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1
#2 0x00007fd46386ef9d in kpeDbgSignalHandler () from /opt/oracle/client/product/19.12.0_64/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1
#3 0x00007fd463162d92 in skgesig_sigactionHandler () from /opt/oracle/client/product/19.12.0_64/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1
#4 <signal handler called>
#5 0x00007fd45fad7555 in unwind_stop () from /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0
#6 0x00007fd45f529bce in _Unwind_ForcedUnwind_Phase2 () from /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
#7 0x00007fd45f52a240 in _Unwind_ForcedUnwind () from /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
#8 0x00007fd45fad7626 in __pthread_unwind () from /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0
#9 0x00007fd45facf46b in pthread_exit () from /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0
#10 0x00007fd45ff9402a in pthread_exit () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
#11 0x00007fd45e2bdd8a in SltsqSigFunc () from /opt/oracle/client/product/19.12.0_64/lib/libclntshcore.so.19.1
#12 0x00007fd45e171bb9 in sslssAsynchHdlr () from /opt/oracle/client/product/19.12.0_64/lib/libclntshcore.so.19.1
#13 0x00007fd45e1715e1 in sslsshandler () from /opt/oracle/client/product/19.12.0_64/lib/libclntshcore.so.19.1
#14 <signal handler called>
#15 0x00007fd45ff37e65 in clone () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
#16 0x00007fd45face0e0 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0
#17 0x00007fd45d96e6c0 in ?? ()
#18 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

I tried running the command info threads to see how many threads are running and below is the result. Is there a way to see the names of these running threads?
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id                                     Frame
* 1    Thread 0x7f0b041496c0 (LWP 3893069) (Exiting) 0x00007f0b068f5acf in raise () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
  2    Thread 0x7f0b0bfcca00 (LWP 481612)            0x00007f0b069d659a in recvfrom () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6

So, what does these stack traces correspond to? GDB is not helping much in this case as the core dump is pointing to somewhere in the Oracle library and not my C code. Can anyone provide more insight into this looking into the stack traces or suggest some other options to try in GDB as I tried whatever I could with my limited knowledge of GDB. Does it seem to be case of memory corruption as the 18th frame from the above trace is showing a NULL address.
I saw a solution to an almost similar issue in the below link: -
what is the reason for core dump? stack shows from oracle lib
So, my next question is if it's the same issue with the ADR parameters as mentioned in the above link, why it's not happening for more than 20 other servers running the same code and having the similar environment (including Oracle version). Also, what is the location of the diagnostics like trace logs, alert logs, etc. so that I can check when they're written to compare the timings with the core dump timings. Finally, is there a particular configured time of the day/week when these traces are written or it can happen anytime?
